# Save data in background task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have background task that recieves notifications for my application. I wanted to add this code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml("<badge version='0' value='" + number + "'/>");
BadgeNotification badge = new BadgeNotification(xmlDoc);
BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(badge);
```

To display number of notifications on the tile. But unfortunetly I have a problem with saving number of recieved notifications. I tried writting singleton and in Run method of Background task to increment it's value but that did not work (alwayes started with 0).

Do you have any ideas that might solve this issue?

Comment: I changed the title to "Save" instead of "Store" because I thought you meant "App Store".